# ExecutorCompletionService is not applicable for the given arguments

Tags: java

In my application, ExecutorCompletionService is used to run couple of tasks which implement Callable. When the tasks are submitted to ExecutorCompletionServer, it gives compile error saying

```
The method submit(Callable<T>) in the type ExecutorCompletionService<T> is not applicable for the arguments (AbstractTask<capture#2-of ? extends Object>)
```

This is how I submit tasks`.

```
List<AbstractTask<? extends Object>> taskList =new ArrayList<>();
        addTasks(new TaskA()); //TaskA,TaskB,TaskC are child classses of AbstractTask. addTasks() method add the child classes to taskList.
        addTasks(new TaskB());
        addTasks(new TaskC());
        List<Future<? extends Object>> futureList= new ArrayList<Future <? extends Object> >();

        final ExecutorService pool = Executors.newFixedThreadPool( TASK_SIZE );

        final ExecutorCompletionService<T> completionService = new ExecutorCompletionService<T >(pool);

        for ( AbstractTask<? extends Object>  callable : taskList) {
                futureList.add( completionService.submit(callable) );
        }
```

This is addTaskMethod.

```
public void addTasks(AbstractTask<? extends Object> task){
            taskList.add(task);
        }
```

This is my AbstractClass.

```
public abstract class AbstractTask<T extends Object> implements
        java.util.concurrent.Callable<T> {

    @Override
    public T call() throws Exception {

        return begin();
    }
    public abstract <B extends Object> B begin() throws RuntimeException ;

}
```

Even the following method 'submit()' in `java.util.concurrent.ExecutorCompletionService<V>` accept arguement as

```
public Future<V> submit(Callable<V> task) {
    if (task == null) throw new NullPointerException();
    RunnableFuture<V> f = newTaskFor(task);
    executor.execute(new QueueingFuture(f));
    return f;
}
```

Why I can't submit my `AbstractTask<? extends Object>`  ? My AbstractTask can have any value which extends from Object. (If I simple remove the `<? extends Object>` in for loop, then it fines.But again My tool:Eclipse warns `Type safety: The expression of type AbstractTask needs unchecked conversion to conform to Callable<T>`. How can I sortout this ? )

**EDIT:** This is TaskA class.

```
public class TaskA  extends AbstractTask<Object> {

    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    @Override
    public java.lang.String begin() throws RuntimeException {
        System.out.println("Task A runs");
        return "A";
    }

}
```

Comment: Where is `addTasks` method?

Comment: @akhil_mittal. Thanks for your attention. My question is modified with the method.

Comment: Why have you written `AbstractTask<T extends Object>` ? I believe `AbstractTask<T>` will work just fine.

Comment: Can you please post class `TaskA` ?

Comment: @akhil_mittal. Thanks for your attention. Class TaskA is added.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're creating an `ExecutorCompletionService<T>`. This is thus an ExecutorCompletionService that accepts instances of `Callable<T>`.

But you're submitting instances of `AbstractTask<? extends Object>`. A `Callable<? extends Object>` is not a `Callable<T>`.

A `Callable<T>` returns instances of T. A `Callable<? extends Object>` returns some unknown type, for which all we know is that the type extends Object. So that's basically like wanting to put unknown objects into a paper shredder . The paper shredder is only able to shred paper, not any kind of object. The compiler prevents you from doing that, because it obviously won't work fine.

You need an `ExecutorCompletionService<Object>`.

Answer (score 1):

In the following line we are creating an instance of `ExecutorCompletionService<T>`

```
final ExecutorCompletionService<T> completionService = new ExecutorCompletionService<T >(pool);
```

It will only accept `Callable<T>` and `submit` will return `Future<T>` and when task is over each `Future<T>` will return result (using `get`) of type `T`.

If we check the signature of `submit` method in `ExecutorCompletionService`:

```
public Future<V> submit(Callable<V> task)
```

Then it specifies the type variable `V` such that all the callables should  be of same type `V`. IMO, Executor Completion Service will not allow a task of type `Callable<? extends Object>` to be submitted because it is like saying that my task extends `Object` which means it can take almost every thing. So we cannot use unbound wildcard with ECS and had to restrict the possible result.

On a side note I believe `Callable<? extends Object>` and `Callable<?>` are same.